# Is there a way to make OpenVZ container with HDD and SSD space at the same time?

Tags: ssd, mount, quota, openvz

I would like to create containers which will have / on hdd and /home on ssd.

I guess it could be done by creating several partitions on ssd and mounting them with http://wiki.openvz.org/Bind_mounts into container. Yes, partitions, not just directories, because of quotas.

Are there any less complicated solutions?